# Deployed changes showed in kudu but not on project website

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have problem with deployment from bitbucket repository into Azure App Service website. Changes on master branch are showed in kudu but not displayed on website. I've figured out possible problem.

[image]

Deployed changes from git repository are being added to client folder, but App Service is probably pointing to /wwwroot/ folder which was updated 2 days ago, that's why I dont see deployed changes. Does anyone have solution on how to fix this?

Comment: You need to restart - and then wait. About 15-20 minutes after restart the changes will automatically reflect.

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT i've deployed changes about 1,5h ago and they are still now showing

Comment: Stop and restart the app in Azure Portal and check once.

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT did it few times already. Dont you think that the problem is that its pointing to the old-version instead of new one? Because I dont know why on kudu I have 2 version of deployment - one from where i've deployed it manually, and second from where i've deployed it from bitbucket

Comment: Please refer  this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70155190/i-cannot-see-the-updates-of-a-web-page-but-my-collegues-can/70183185#70183185)

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT could you post your visual code solution? Didnt tried it, only tried cache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240204/discussion-between-harshithaveeramalla-mt-and-dronikk).